# Organizing file output problems

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, io, count

I am working on a program to organize a list of numbers from a file and output these numbers in a easier to read format. Such as a file called `Counting.txt` containing the numbers:

```
11

1 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 7
```

and I want it to output:

```
1x2 2x1 3x1 4x4 5x2 7x1
```

The formula for output being `vXc`, where `v` is the number and `c` is the number of times it occurs. But my current program only outputs it as:

```
1x1 2x1 3x1 4x1 4x1 4x1 4x1 5x1 5x1 7x1
```

I believe there is a small error in my for loop that doesn't allow me to change my `c` variable, or the number indicating how many times the actual number occurs. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  FILE* file = fopen("counting.txt", "r");
  int total_num, count = 1, num, num2, i;

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Did not find counting.txt file.\n");
  }

  fscanf(file, "%d", &total_num);
  fscanf(file, "%d", &num);

  for (i = 1; i < total_num; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%d", &num);

    if (num2 == num) {
      count = count + 1;
    } else {
      printf("%dX%d ", num, count);
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop you read into `num` instead of `num2`. So in general `num2` is undefined. You also need at the end of each loop's iteration to assign to `num` the value of `num2`.

Also when you print the number of repetitions you should refer to the old value and not the current one, since you don't know if the current number will be followed by other equal numbers.

So you could change your loop to:

```
for (i=1; i< total_num; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%d", &num2);
    if (num2 == num) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("%dX%d ", num, count);
        count = 1;
    }
    num = num2;
 }
 printf("%dX%d ", num, count);
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm still a little lost. :( What would that look like in the actual code?

Comment: That helped its almost there! But with the revised loop it outputs:            2x2 3x1 4x1 5x4 7x2 7x1                                                                                                         Where the desired output is:                                                                       1x2 2x1 3x1 4x4 5x2 7x1

Comment: I got it!! I changed num2, in the else statement to num and it works like a charm! Thanks so much!!